# How to create build the next not visible widgets on the ListView?

Tags: flutter, listview

We know that `ListView.builder` only build the widgets visible on the screen at the moment, but suppose we want to build those and the next fives widgets? So when we scroll, the next fives are already built?

How can we achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cacheExtent` property to make the ListView build and layout the given size beyond the visible area.